# How to wait completing of event subscriber with Observable call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two components. Child component has an event (EventEmitter). Parent component has handler with long time method.

I need to wait for finishing of executing of my method (longTimeMethod) before further actions. Method continues near 5 seconds.

I want to reach execution of all steps consistently (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5).

But now sequence is 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-selector',
    template: '<>********</>'
})
export class ChildComponent{
    @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter();

    someFunction() {
       // Step 1: event emit

        this.childEvent.emit();
        // Step 5: Subscribers execution finished
        // Some code which should to reached after all event subscribers
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-selector',
    template: '<child-selector (childEvent)="handleChildEvent()"></child-selector>'
})

export class ParentComponent{
       // Step 2: handler start 
    handleChildEvent() {
        // this.longTimeMethod return Observable<void>
        this.myService.longTimeMethod()
            .subscribe(() => {
                // Step 3: Method executing finished
            });
    // Step 4: Another code
    }
}
```

I tried to use async-await approach:

```
async handleChildEvent() {
    // this.longTimeMethod return Observable<void>
    await this.myService.longTimeMethod().toPromise()
        .then(() => {
            // Step 3: Method executing finished
        });
       // Step 4: Another code
}
```

Sequence changed but it's still not correct:  1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4.
How to accomplish correct behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delay step5 emit a callback from child.

```js
export class ChildComponent{
  @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter();

  someFunction() {
    // Step 1: event emit
    this.childEvent.emit(execStep5);
  }

  execStep5() {
    // Step 5: Subscribers execution finished
    // Some code which should to reached after all event subscribers
  }
}
```

Execute `execStep5` in the parent when ready

```js
handleChildEvent(execStep5) {
  ...
// Step 4: Another code
execStep5();
```

For step3 & step4, change `subscribe` to `map`, ***then*** subscribe and execute step4 and the callback.
Don't use await/async, since rxjs already has these tools - don't mix two methods.

```js
export class ParentComponent{
  // Step 2: handler start 
  handleChildEvent(execStep5) {
    // this.longTimeMethod return Observable<void>
    this.myService.longTimeMethod()
      .map(() => {
        // Step 3: Method executing finished
        return Observable.of('done');
      })
      .subscribe(() => {
        // Step 4: Another code
        execStep5();
      });
  }
}
```

There is probably even shorter code to do this, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this solution in similar situations but not exactly the same. Since your problem now only lies in step 5 not being in order, you can wrap step 5 in a setTimeout function with 0 wait. This will cause that step 5 be a scheduled task.

```
    setTimeout(_ => {/*step 5 code*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

I face it when trying in a web component standalone app to call to some function in a hosted app (angular, in my case).

So using the `EventEmitter` class from Angular or from the Stencil (in the web component app) wasn't an option, as it's 2 different framework-based apps.

and basically, Event Emitting is an observable design pattern, not intended for synchronous promise-based actions.

**So here is my solution:**

Child component / app:

```
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent {   
  @Prop() parentFunction: () => Promise<void>; 
  ....
  await this.parentFunction();
}
```

Parent component / app:

in HTML:

```
<child [parentFunction]='this.onParentFunction.bind(this)'></child>
```

in Ts file:

```
 async onParentFunction() {
   await this.sessionService.refreshSession();    
 }
```