# Angular2+ service to notify multiple components and collect results for checking

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

My goal is to create a service that, when called, pushes out event and waits for subscribers to return data. Once all subscribers to called event are finished, component which triggered the service call proceeds with their responses.

I took a look at passing another event emitter as parameter of the first call, or solutions mentioned in [How to wait completing of event subscriber with Observable call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173454/how-to-wait-completing-of-event-subscriber-with-observable-call), but I don't feel knowledgable enough to judge the correct implementation on my own.

I attach a stackblitz with examble of this - parent sends out error checking event and should collect responses from all subscribed components before executing additional code.

[Error checking accross components - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-checking-across-components?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The `@Input()`/`@Output` and `EventEmitter` exists for communication between components and shouldn't be used in services.

A solution would be to have your components to register to the service:

```js
export class ErrorMessageService {

  private registeredComponents: ErrorCheckingComponent[] = [];

  public registerComponent(component: ErrorCheckingComponent) {
    this.registeredComponents.push(component);
  }

  public removeComponent(component: ErrorCheckingComponent) {
    const index = this.registeredComponents.findIndex(c => c === component);
    this.registeredComponents.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public async checkErrors() {
    const allErrors = (await Promise.all(this.registeredComponents.map(c => c.checkError()))).flat();
    console.log(allErrors);
    // logic after all checks
  }

}
```

Where `ErrorCheckingComponent` is an interface that the child components would implement:

```js
export interface ErrorCheckingComponent {
  checkError(): Promise<string[]>;
}
```

Then your child component would be like the following

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ErrorCheckingComponent {

  constructor(private errorMessageService: ErrorMessageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.errorMessageService.registerComponent(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.errorMessageService.removeComponent(this);
  }

  checkError(): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(['error 1', 'error 2']), 5000));
  }
}
```

I didn't test any of this but I hope you got the idea

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out on my use-case. Am I to understand that Promise returns (and this notifies) immediately but provides value after some delay, or that the crucial thing is the parent component keeping a ref list of all subscribers?

And can I run into issues if I start checking errors across different component classes? How should I handle typing when neither of them implements a common Component type?